# Is it possible to get the "Might of the Earth" set with Bloodshards?

Tags: diablo-iii

I wonder if it would be possible to get the `Might of the Earth` set thru the Bloodshard vendor.

It's not possible to get class item sets like `Tal Rashas`, `Inna's` or `Immortal King's`.
But could you get a themed sets like `Might of the Earth`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to get this from Kadala.

Might of the Earth [is a Torment-only set](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10189299133). Prior to patch 2.05, [Torment-only legendaries could not be gained from Kadala.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12248064907?page=2#23). However, as of Patch 2.05, [you can now gain Torment-only legendaries from Kadala](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/#amkadala).

Answer (score 2):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#amkadala). You can get Torment only items from Kadala now. It does not specify that you have to be in Torment difficulty.

> - Can now drop Torment only Legendary items
> - Will now always give you weapon types that your character can equip with an emphasis on class specific weapon types
> - Bug Fix: Fixed an issue causing Kadala to sometimes give common quality Crusader Shields